# How to ensure process ends before launching a command on CMD?

Tags: c#, python, pip

I have a created a small app that would download and Install Python and then install a list of Python Libraries using pip.

I am using the Process.WaitForExit() method to make sure that the installation of Python is complete before I begin the libraries installation. Below is my code for installing Python

```
 public void installPython()
        {
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Python36\python-3.6.3-amd64.exe";
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();

        }
```

Below is the code which then launches cmd and executes the pip command :

```
public void installLibraries()
        {

            int exitCode;
            string command = "pip install -r requirements.txt";
            ProcessStartInfo processInfo;
            Process process;

            processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + command);
            processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

            processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

            process = Process.Start(processInfo);
            process.WaitForExit();


            string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

            exitCode = process.ExitCode;

            Console.WriteLine("output>>" + (String.IsNullOrEmpty(output) ? "(none)" : output));
            Console.WriteLine("error>>" + (String.IsNullOrEmpty(error) ? "(none)" : error));
            Console.WriteLine("ExitCode: " + exitCode.ToString(), "ExecuteCommand");
            process.Close();
        }
```

Then in the Main method I call the installPython method and then the installLibraries method

Unfortunately the compiled .exe isn't following the correct order. When I run the command from the cmd after browsing to the directory, I get the error :

```
output>>(none)
error>>'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Is there a mistake in how I am using the Process functions?

Comment: You dont have pip installed.Download pip by `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py` then `python get-pip.py` to install

Comment: Once the Exe exits, I’m able to run pip in another command window. Pip is installed once Python installation is complete. The issue is that the pip method is called before the installation is complete.

Comment: I think this is a normal behavior with windows. When you install a program that can be run from the command line, all command windows open before the installation cannot run that program. You must launch a new command window after the installation. Speaking from experience.

Comment: Can you check if the environment variables are set once your method installPython() is complete?

I think that is where the problem is.

Comment: The path variables are set right. I was able to select add path variable during Python installation.

Answer (score 0):

This is Start process and wait until finished.

```cs
        public static void StartProcessAndWait(string processFile, string arguments, string workingDirectory)
        {
            var proc = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = processFile,
                    Arguments = arguments,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = true,
                    RedirectStandardError = true,
                    WorkingDirectory = workingDirectory
                }
            };

            proc.Start();


            var _ = ConsumeReader(proc.StandardOutput);
            // ReSharper disable once RedundantAssignment
            _ = ConsumeReader(proc.StandardError);

            async Task ConsumeReader(TextReader reader)
            {
                string text;

                while ((text = await reader.ReadLineAsync()) != null)
                    Console.WriteLine(text);
            }

            proc.WaitForExit(30000);
        }
```